# Using hashmaps and matching values

Tags: kotlin, hashmap, key-value-store

I re-made my code a bit to make it more clear of my scope. Hope it's more understandable now! I also added in-code instructions to make it more understandable! Essentially I want to match the 2 hashmaps based on the same ages in the hashmaps. This should also work when I add new ages to the collections!

```
fun main() {
    val allMen = AllMenInfo2()
    allMen.takeUserName()

}

open class AllMenInfo2 {

    // This code contains pre-made keys-value pairs for men respective women in a Class.
    // These represent name and age!
    // I want to add a new MAN with a name and an age to the hashmap of allMenInfo.

    val allMen = hashMapOf(Pair("Bob", 18), Pair("Ken", 21), Pair("Jerry", 25))
    val allWomen = hashMapOf(Pair("Alice", 19), Pair("Rebeca", 20), Pair("Olivia", 27))


    // This takes userInput of name.

    open fun takeUserName() {
        println("Enter your name!")
        val userName = readLine() ?: ""
        val names = userName
        println(allMen)

        // This takes userinput of age and adds both name and age to the hashmap of allMenInfo!

        try {
            println("Please enter your age!")
            val ageOfUsers = readLine() ?: ""
            val ages = ageOfUsers.toInt()
            allMen.put(names, ages)


        } catch (E: Exception) {
            println("Invalid number/name, please try again!")
        }


    }

}
```

Here I need to be able to compare all the men's ages (allMen) to all the women's ages (allWomen)
and only printout the ages of women who matches the ages in both collections.
Example:

1. I input "Smith" - 20 - to the men's hashmap. This should give me: "Rebecca, 20" from allWomen. Since those 2 only has the same matching age's across both collections.
   How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you want if there are multiple women of same age?

Comment: Why comparing men age to women age if you only (seem to) need to filter women's age ?

Comment: If there are multiple women of the same age as I input, they should all match with my input. Example, there are 2 women with age 21. If i input 21, those 2 women should be match with my input.

Comment: Well I want to filter the same ages of allMen and allWomen but with the added functionality of my own input. Meaning based on the age I put in, which is added to the allMen hashmap. If the ages are identical in allmen and allWomen, those who are identical in age will be printed out to the console!

Comment: You keep saying you want to "compare the men's ages to the women's ages" but all your examples are putting in an age and only checking the women's group for matches against that one value. We get that you're adding data to the men's group, but you're not involving that group in any of your comparison/matching examples. That's why people keep asking you to clarify - and you should update your question when you do, not post a new one and lose all the context

Comment: Oh I see, yeah that makes sense now. My bad!. I guess I want to compare all the men's ages to all the women's ages and find matches based on the age similarity/same age. With the possibility of adding new names and ages to the men variable but still doing the same process of checking and matching ages. Will also update the question! @cactustictacs

Comment: I mean I gave you two examples on your other question - one for finding all the women with a specific age using `filter`, and one for making groups of people (men and women) with the same age using `groupBy`. Isn't one of those what you want? It seems like you want the first one, `allWomen.filter { (_, age) -> age == 20 }` which gives you a list of all the women who are age 20? If that's not what you need, it would help if you explain *why* - people keep giving you solutions to your problem (it's not complicated!) and you just tell them the problem again, we're just going round in circles

Comment: the .filter method only filters out if I place a pre-set value. In your case it is set to == 20. but this means it wont match other ages such as if 1 man and 1 women has 25 years ( 1 man of 25 years in allMen collection and  1 women of 25 years in allWomen collection)

Comment: I want to be able to match ages in 1 collection(allMen) to the same ages in the other collection(allWomen), regardless of a pre-set value. It should match dependent on the ages in both collections. I think therefore groupBy would be more suitable for this, but how would I go about doing it ?

Comment: We're narrowing down the actual question, but I think we still need to clarify what _output_ you want. A merged map from age to the names of all men and women with that age? The same, but including only ages belonging to at least one man _and_ at least one woman? A list of women with the same age as at least one man?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @gidds. When you put it that way it makes more sense! I am more looking towards the first one you wrote "A merged map from age to the names of all men and women with that age?" . We can focus on the one you mentioned first for now but you did spark my interest with this one as well "A list of women with the same age as at least one man". But lets focus on the first one for now! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Comments have clarified that the desired output is a merged map from age to the names of all men and women with that age.)

The simplest solution I can see is a one-liner:

```
val allMen = mapOf("Bob" to 18, "Ken" to 21, "Jerry" to 25, "TwinM" to 22)
val allWomen = mapOf("Alice" to 19, "Rebeca" to 20, "Olivia" to 27, "TwinF" to 22)

val merged = (allMen + allWomen).entries.groupBy({ it.value }, { it.key })
```

That gives a map of:

```
{18=[Bob], 19=[Alice], 20=[Rebeca], 21=[Ken], 22=[TwinM, TwinF], 25=[Jerry], 27=[Olivia]}
```

It uses the two-lambda form of [`groupBy()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html#kotlin.collections$groupBy(kotlin.collections.Iterable((kotlin.collections.groupBy.T)),%20kotlin.Function1((kotlin.collections.groupBy.T,%20kotlin.collections.groupBy.K)),%20kotlin.Function1((kotlin.collections.groupBy.T,%20kotlin.collections.groupBy.V)))) that lets you transform the values too (else they'd be pairs including the age too).

(You'll note that I've added a man and a woman with the same age, to illustrate the effect. I've also used the infix function [`to`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html), which was created for exactly this case.)

---

There's a problem with this approach, though: it doesn't cope if a man and a woman have the same name (e.g. "Pat"). If there were, then it would omit one of them from the result. (That probably isn't a concern for you, given that the maps you're using already prevents the possibility of two men with the same name, or two women.)

To fix this, you could convert the map entries to sequences, concatenate them, and then group that, which you can also do in one line:

```
val allMen = mapOf("Bob" to 18, "Ken" to 21, "Jerry" to 25, "TwinM" to 22, "Pat" to 30)
val allWomen = mapOf("Alice" to 19, "Rebeca" to 20, "Olivia" to 27, "TwinF" to 22, "Pat" to 31)

val merged = (allMen.asSequence() + allWomen.asSequence()).groupBy({ it.value }, { it.key })
```

Giving:

```
{18=[Bob], 19=[Alice], 20=[Rebeca], 21=[Ken], 22=[TwinM, TwinF], 25=[Jerry], 27=[Olivia], 30=[Pat], 31=[Pat]}
```

---

To handle two men or two women with the same name, you'd need a different data structure to start with. For example, instead of anonymous keys and values, you could create a simple data class to represent a person:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

You could then create your data as simple lists:

```
val men = listOf(Person("Bob", 18), Person("Ken", 21), Person("Jerry", 25), Person("TwinM", 22), Person("Pat", 30), Person("Bob", 17))
val women = listOf(Person("Alice", 19), Person("Rebecca", 20), Person("Olivia", 27), Person("TwinF", 22), Person("Pat", 31))
```

(You might think that sets would be more suitable — but that wouldn't handle two people with the same name *and* age, which is always possible if rare. Lists may not seem natural if there's no inherent ordering of people, but at least they'll handle all cases. Also, I've added a second "Bob", with a different age from the first, to illustrate.)

You could then merge them with a similar one-liner:

```
val personsByAge = (men + women).groupBy({ it.age }, { it.name })
```

Giving:

```
{17=[Bob], 18=[Bob], 19=[Alice], 20=[Rebecca], 21=[Ken], 22=[TwinM, TwinF], 25=[Jerry], 27=[Olivia], 30=[Pat], 31=[Pat]}
```

Not only is this the simplest version, it's also easier to read (with meaningful fields `age` and `name` instead of the previous `key` and `value`), and is probably easier to maintain and debug.

Comment: Thank you very much @gidds! This was exactly what I was looking for! It also is very well explained with answers that goes through it all. This is exactly the reason why I thought HashMaps would be the best solution since Lists can contain duplicates ( which I dont want) and Sets can only contain 1 unique "Value" and not handle the same name and age. So i went with HashMap which I thought would solve it. But you showed me now that there is a more efficient way by using a Data Class + Lists! I still have a lot to learn but thank you again for the elegant explanation. Wish you all the best!